# How to specify input language for Entry or any other input field?

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, tkinter-entry

In short, i try to type letters (in input components like "Entry", "Text") that are allowed by Windows language-keyboard (i'm using "Latvan(QWERTY)" keyboard) and i can't write long letters like 'ā', 'č', 'ģ' and others.

For example, when i try to write 'ā', the result is 'â'.

The interesting part - when i focus on specific GUI input fiend and change Windows keyboard-language (with "Alt+Shift" shortcut or manually) twice (for example, from "Latvan(QWERTY)" to "Russian" and back to "Latvan(QWERTY)") - then i can write all letters i needed.

What i want is to set all input fields keyboard-language so i could write all letters i want without doing things mentioned above every time i launch my GUI program.

If you need more info or there is already place where this question is answered, please leave a comment and i will act accordingly.

**Edit 1:**

I am using [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) to write my Python Tkinter code. I tried to assign necessary keyboard to my program's generated GUI form according to [this guide](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-set-language-on-a-per-app-basis-in-windows-10/) but it didn't work (i guess that because i used it on temporary created GUI forms).

Comment: as for me it is system's problem and tkinter has nothing to do with this. maybe there is in system function which can assign different keyboards to different programs. At least [linux has this function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655628/assign-default-keyboard-language-per-application)

Comment: if you can change language using shortcut then maybe you could use [pynput](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html) to send this combination to system.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by using [pynput](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html).

Here is simplified version of my final code:

```
from tkinter import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

def change_keyboard_lang(event):
    keyboard = Controller()
    for i in range(2):
        keyboard.press(Key.alt)
        keyboard.press(Key.shift_l)
        keyboard.release(Key.shift_l)
        keyboard.release(Key.alt)

root = Tk()

word_input = Entry(root)
word_input.focus_set()
word_input.bind("<FocusIn>", change_keyboard_lang)
word_input.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In short, if cursor is focused on Entry field "word_input", system calls function "change_keyboard_lang" that changes input language from original to other and back to original - and now i can write necessary letters.

It's not the best solution since i need to bind event to every input field in my GUI form but it gets the job done. If you have a better solution please post it here.

Comment: try `root.bind_class("Entry", "<FocusIn>", change_keyboard_lang)` to bind to all Entry at once. Doc: [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: Please consider marking [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) as accepted. [See this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.