# How can i use symbols that are not in ASCII table in tkinter window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, encoding, utf-8

I can not write in my native language (Georgian) in `tkinter` window (`Entry` and `Text` Widgets). When I try to do that question marks are displayed instead of characters i am typing. In my opinion I need to add `UTF-8` encoding in my code but i don`t know where and how.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

win.geometry('400x300')
win.resizable(False, False)

Label(win, text="Enter your name:").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

name = Entry(win)
name.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)


def reg_click():
    temp = name.get()
    res_text.delete(0.0, END)
    res_text.insert(0.0, f"Hello {temp}!")


Button(win, text='Registration', command=reg_click, padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10)

res_text = Text(win, width=20, height=3)
res_text.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

win.mainloop()
```

And this is a result:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the font to one that includes unicode characters? Maybe your system's default font isn't unicode-aware.

Comment: Yes I tried that but same result.

Comment: I have tried various fonts.

Comment: name = Entry(win, font="sylfaen 12") - this is the way i am doing that. Do you mean something different?

Comment: Check `change_keyboard_lang` in [How to specify input language for Entry or any other input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57091629).